# Detect corners of XKCD comic panels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, corner-detection

I'm trying to detect the panels of xkcd comics so that I can cut them out. I want to retrieve random XKCD comics (implemented) and reliably know where the corners of panels are. My ideal output would be something like this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Where I have some or all of the corners of panels.
I have an array containing the entire comic, and my approach so far has been to find the large contours, as so:

```
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    conts=[]
    if len(contours) > 1:
        conts = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]
```

And then detect corners using cv2.approxPolyDP. It seems my contouring is not sufficient however, as I usually don't get nice corners, and when I draw the contours, they don't seem that good.

A good run:

[image: Good run]
(some dots fall onto corners)

A bad one:

[image: bad run]
(girl is covered in dots)

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with my contours, like maybe not choosing the right mode (I chose RETR_EXTERNAL because the comic panels are fairly external).

The comics are normally grayscale but sometimes not, so I'm converting to grayscale and using a binary threshold prior to contour detection.

Some other thoughts:

1. Would edge detection maybe be more suitable for this task?
2. I've also noticed that the array I have has the border right at the edge of the picture, so would padding help?
3. The comics are somewhat variable so would a brute force method maybe work better?

Comment: Maybe a hough transform can help, although I'm not sure how it performs with line drawings: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

Comment: Could you be clear about whether your comics actually have window decorations (such as *Maximise*, *Minimise* buttons and frames) or not, please? Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code. Contours should be found on white areas not black. So you need to invert your image if you want to get contours on the black rectangles of your frames.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, no, those are just from OpenCV output. I'll look into hough and inversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is the contour area will tell you something about how complex the path can be.
I'd go a simpler metric such as the height of the contour's [`boundingRect()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#bounding-rectangle):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'boyfriend.png'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, dst = cv2.threshold(gray, 127 ,255,0)
# erode and negate to amplify edges
dst = cv2.erode(dst,None,iterations=2)
dst = (255-dst)

cv2.imshow('thresh', dst)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dst, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

if len(contours) > 1:
    # print bounding box height per contour for debugging purposes
    print([cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[3] for cnt in contours])
    # filter contours where the bounding box height matches the image height
    conts = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[3] == img.shape[0]]
    # preview
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, conts, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Notice 3 contour bounding box heights stand out:

```
[127, 16, 16, 16, 16, 35, 15, 36, 16, 16, 16, 18, 17, 17, 220, 220, 220]
```

You may want to optionally change the condition to a threshold instead of an exact value.
e.g.

```
# if the contour bounding box height is > 3/4 of the image height
cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[3] > img.shape[0] * 0.75
```

the full code above produces:
[image: xkcd panel detection]

Notice that I'm using a [morphological filter](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to amplify the edges.
It works for that image with those iterations as the filter expands the box outlines enough but not so much that they merge with the text / characters.
This maybe something to tweak for other images.

**Update** Doing a quick search I found a couple of potentially interesting resources:

[Kumiko](https://github.com/njean42/kumiko)

> Kumiko, the Comics Cutter is a set of tools to compute useful information about comic book pages, panels, and more. Its main strength is to find out the locations of panels within a comic's page (image file). Kumiko can also compile information about panels for all pages in a comic book, and present it as one piece of data (JSON-formatted object).
> [image: kumiko xkcd panel detection]

[**Segmentation and indexation of complex objects in
comic book images**](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01221308/document) (different from what you're asking, however potentially useful for next steps)

Comment: Wow, very comprehensive. Thank you for your answer, these look promising.

Comment: I ended up using Kumiko and adapting their command-line tool to inline python. See: https://github.com/njean42/kumiko/issues/6#issuecomment-817550566